# access control to data-center using rfid

Tags: access-control, physical

I don't know if "here" is the right place to make this kind of question...
so here it is..

1. Is rfid a good solution for controlling access to a data-center?
2. Because rfid is "wireless", is it hackable?
3. Is a biometric solution more secure?
4. For accessing a data-center, should I use a hybrid solution, like for example a biometric solution in conjunction with rfid?
5. Can any of you tell me a good solution, biometric, rfid or hybrid (with links to research more information)?

Any answers and opinions appreciated

Jorge

Comment: This question needs a lot more definition to be appropriately answered.  Without knowing anything about your environment and applicable regulatory obligations, nobody here can give a good answer as to what you "should" do.

Answer (score 10):

Some simple answers - with description:

**1. Is rfid a good solution for controlling access to a data-center?**

Not necessarily - because RFID broadcasts a signal, that can be picked up. In simple implementations a simple replay attack may be enough. Is RFID in a card? If so, what are the controls around it? ie if I steal the card do I have access, or do I also need a pass code?

**2. Because rfid is "wireless", is it hackable?**

Not a real question. Wireless does not make something hackable. The implementation could be good or bad. An attacker can pick up data remotely though, so factor this in.

**3. Is a biometric solution more secure?**

Biometric solutions have issues - the main one being that your biometric identifier is unlikely to be unique. The more unique it is made (through refining parameters) the more false negatives you will get, and if it is a fingerprint, what happens if your finger is damaged? Check out any studies on crossover points to see how appropriate it might be for your situation. Generally biometrics are used in addition to other mechanisms.

**4. For accessing a data-center, should I use a hybrid solution, like for example a biometric solution in conjunction with rfid?**

That would be better than biometrics alone.

**5. Can any of you tell me a good solution, biometric, rfid or hybrid (with prices(a website link were I can research for more information))?**

I don't have any published data. The implementations I have seen have been for trusted CA's - the protection they put in place includes physical keys, biometrics, dual-man controls, man traps and weight measurement on entry and exit...possibly overkill for this application?